#  uploading large GIFS with Kusaba

Tags: php

This doesn't always happen. I could upload the same GIF sometimes and sometimes receive back this error, it seems almost random.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /webroot/i/n/*001/*.org/www/inc/classes/board-post.class.php on line 81
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/classes/board-post.class.php:81) in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/board.php on line 343
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/classes/board-post.class.php:81) in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/board.php on line 347
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/classes/board-post.class.php:81) in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/board.php on line 350
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/func/posts.php on line 249
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/classes/board-post.class.php on line 136
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/classes/board-post.class.php on line 163
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/func/fetching.php on line 27
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/classes/board-post.class.php on line 343
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/classes/board-post.class.php on line 443
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/func/fetching.php on line 27
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/classes/board-post.class.php:81) in /webroot/i/n/*/*.org/www/inc/func/misc.php on line 76
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you're using a variable that's not an array in a `foreach` statement, like:

```
$foo = 123;
foreach ($foo as $bar)
```

This throws the `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` warning. Check your variables better to make sure they're arrays when they're expected to be.

The fact that this warning was thrown and output blocks headers from being sent, which causes the other `Cannot modify header information` warning.

Comment: This is line 80 to 84 of the first error.
   foreach ($results[0] as $key=>$line) {

    if (!is_numeric($key)) {

     $this->board[$key] = $line;

    }

   }

Comment: @Tom That means `$results[0]` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cycle through the `$results` array, you should write

`foreach ($results as $key=>$value)`

rather than

`foreach ($results[0] as $key=>$value)`

unless `$results[0]` itself is an array, in which case `$results` would be a matrix (array of arrays).